# Chrome Plugin Storage : Local Testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Code snippet:

---

```
if(localStorage.getItem("recording")!= null && localStorage.getItem("recording")=="true" && action.element!=null){

actions.push(action);

actions=processActions(actions);

localStorage.setItem("actions",JSON.stringify(actions));
}
```

---

With recent version of chrome have started to face issues testing chrome extension with local storage. We have developed an chrome extension which requires storage access.

In Local, we used to upload unpacked extension and then we were able to test the plugin. However, recently we are required to publish it to web store and only then we can test the plugin. This increases time to fix an issue and if there is a bug in the logic, it could get even messier.

Has any 1 faced similar issues or have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Another error which frequently pops up: Unchecked runtime.lastError: IO error: .../000001.dbtmp: Could not rename file: File currently in use. (ChromeMethodBFE: 14::RenameFile::2)

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage