# Chrome Extension Chrome.Storage Calls Fail Due to "IO error: .../000001.dbtmp: Could not rename file: File currently in use"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error, chromium

I have a Chrome extension that I have been writing that utilizes the Chrome.storage.sync.get and Chrome.storage.sync.set API calls in order to store and retrieve user settings. It works perfectly fine on my desktop computer (Version 87.0.4280.88 64-bit Windows 10), however when attempting to install on my corporate-managed Chrome (Version 86.0.4240.198 64-bit Windows 10) I received the following error when attempting to save the options that function on my desktop:

"**options.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: IO error: .../000001.dbtmp: Could not rename file: File currently in use. (ChromeMethodBFE: 14::RenameFile::2)**"

I searched around and see many issues surrounding ChromeMethodBFE: 15::..., but only a few results for this and only one specific from a few weeks ago: [Chrome Plugin Storage : Local Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070362/chrome-plugin-storage-local-testing)

Has anyone seen this before either on this build, or in the past, that might have some idea about what to do about it? My extensions in the past have worked on my corporate-managed laptops before for using the chrome.storage calls, however it seems that it may be related to this version. When it hits this exception, it returns an undefined object that doesn't allow me to use anything, so it isn't something I can catch too easily.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: For posterity, I am being told by my organization that this was related to a known issue with a version of their DLP software. It was corrected in future releases.